# Aftre update deletion of row

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table called 'second'

```
   TABLE public.second
  (
  userid bigint,
  companyid bigint
    )
```

and table called visibility_matrix

```
 CREATE TABLE public.visibility_matrix
(
   name character varying,
   companyid bigint
 )
```

I created a trigger after I update the 'second' table I want to delete the row in visibility matrix ,I tried to achieve it via deleting the row with the companyid in visibility_matrix but it didn't work,any suggestions? here is the trigger:

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pos_org_rel_refresh()
      RETURNS trigger AS

```
$$  
  DECLARE
  r Integer ;

BEGIN  


IF TG_OP='UPDATE' THEN

DELETE FROM visibility_matrix where companyid=NEW.companyid;
END IF;


  END;
$$  
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';  

  CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger  
  AFTER UPDATE OR DELETE
  ON second
  FOR EACH ROW  
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE pos_org_rel_refresh();
```

Comment: is the trigger being executed? can you post the code that creates the trigger itself?

Comment: It is the same besides the last 2 rows :D

Comment: I meant the code that starts with `CREATE TRIGGER`, to make sure that the trigger is actually created, do you see it there when you `\d second` ?

Comment: I understand,I edited it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing a return statement, this should fix it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pos_org_rel_refresh() RETURNS trigger AS

$$  
  DECLARE
  r Integer ;

BEGIN  


IF TG_OP='UPDATE' THEN

    DELETE FROM visibility_matrix where companyid=NEW.companyid;
    RETURN NEW;
END IF;

RETURN NULL;
END;
$$  
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: I updated the field,but I get the error: ERROR:  record "new" has no field "companyid"
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "DELETE FROM visibility_matrix where companyid=NEW.companyid"
PL/pgSQL function pos_org_rel_refresh() line 10 at SQL statement

Comment: Can you confirm that table second has a column companyid ? Also what is the query that is producing this error?